# paypal pro vendor,partner,userids

Tags: php, paypal

I am newbie.I want to integrate paypal pro hosted soloution for my website.I have created paypal pro account and its showing in my profile.The issue is I want to integrate it in sandbox and for that I have created code.Code is working f9.

The issue is I dont know what is my parter name,my vendor,user and the password.I have tried with my paypal credentials but it gives me the error.

Payflow call failed

Array
(
    [RESULT] => 1
    [RESPMSG] => User authentication failed
    [SECURETOKENID] => MySecTokenID-5468d69e19b1d
)

I have tried to login to manager.paypal.com with my credentials but it also give me an error(Bad name or password).

I have spent 2 days in searching but got no help.Kindly help me how to solve this issue.

Comment: You must have recieve an email from paypal team regarding the vendor and username.

Comment: Yes, when you were first approved you should have received login details for the manager.paypal.com site.  Those same credentials are what you use in the API calls, and you'll use the same value for bother username and vendor.